# list[box|view|whatever] with an 'add new...' item at the end

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to create a wpf control consisting of a list with an element at the end to add a new item (kind of what some grids have). I've been googling around trying to find a similar component but I've found nothing.

I'm new to wpf and willing to write it from scratch if there is nothing similar.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You should handle this at the ViewModel level. Does your `ListBox` have any special `ItemTemplate`? Post the relevant XAML or a screenshot of what you need.

Comment: @HighCore, thanks. What I want is just a simple listbox showing items and with a last element saying 'add new...' or something that can be clicked to display a textbox

Answer (score 0):

A `DataGrid` can do that (does so [by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.canuseraddrows.aspx)), if your item has no default constructor you can use a [`BindingList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) and factory code via the [`AddingNew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132741.aspx) event, of course your collection needs to implement `IList` so items can be added in any case.

For other controls you can also bind them to [collection views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx) that support adding, in that case you need to style the [`NewItemPlaceholder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.newitemplaceholder.aspx) (make it a `Button` with adding logic for example).